Does Azure DevOps cargo artifact feed support cargo search?
As part of my build validations I want my pipeline to check that the version number in a feature branch of my lib crate is strictly greater than the previously published version on my cargo feed. This is to ensure that after a PR has been merged, publishing the crate doesn't fail because the version number wasn't bumped.
To get the remote version number I have tried using cargo search but it seems like it's not supported as it always responds with a 404 saying:
error: failed to retrieve search results from the registry at https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/cf4789c3-fe81-4003-8668-deadbeef/_packaging/d7cc3967-810b-43cb-bc0e-deadbeef/cargo

Is cargo search not supported yet? If so, is there a plan to support it in the future?
Is there a different way I could achieve my goal?

I can reproduce the same issue when using the cargo search command.  After successful authentication, it returns a 404 error.

I am afraid that the cargo search command doesn't support using Azure DevOps artifacts feed.
You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community which is our main forum for product suggestions to report this feature.

Is there a different way I could achieve my goal?

To meet your requirement, you can consider using the Azure DevOps Rest API to get the package versions: Artifact Details - Get Packages
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?includeAllVersions=true&api-version=7.1

Here is the Powershell script sample:
$token = "PAT"

$Org = "Orgname"

$Project = "ProjectName"

$feedname = "feedname"

$Packagename = "packageName"

$GetFeedurl="https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$($Org)/$($Project)/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=7.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetFeedurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

foreach($feed in $response.value)
{
    if($feed.name -eq $feedname)
    {
       $feedid = $feed.id
    }
}



$GetPackage ="https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$($Org)/$($Project)/_apis/packaging/Feeds/$($feedid)/packages?includeAllVersions=true&api-version=7.1"

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetPackage -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


foreach($package in $response1.value)
{
    if($package.name -eq $Packagename)
    {
       $versions= $package.versions.version
    }
}

echo $Packagename

echo $versions

Result:
Feed Package versions:

Script Output:

